# TypeError: Window.getComputedStyle: Argument 1 is not an object

Tags: angular, getcomputedstyle

When initialize keen-slider in iframe then this error is shown. In chrome this is working but shows error in case of firefox (version 119).
Initilaize keen-slider like this:

```
this.slider = new KeenSlider(this.sliderRef.nativeElement, {});
```

I didn't get any solution for this.

Comment: Also getting that error.